# Add sharing support for China, like WeChat

Tags: feature-request, sharing

When I want to share a good question, I am presented with three alternatives:
[image]

Sadly:

- China blocks Google+
- China blocks Facebook (and Instagram and WhatsApp, etc.)
- China blocks Twitter

So, may you add, for instance, [WeChat](https://www.wechat.com/en/) sharing?

Comment: you could, in theory, paste the link into wechat.

Comment: We will probably never add more services there, nor do we want to create some popup with every known social media service. All of these sites work perfectly fine with just copy-pasting the direct link, and that's already what we all do anyways rather than using the actual icon.

Comment: You can also use the SE app, and it lets you share with whatever app you want

Comment: When you start this kind of question, everyone will want their fav (web)apps to be added too, like: WhatsApp, LINE, Telegram, Viber, reddit, etc...

Comment: Already existed icons should be probably deleted to be fair ...

Comment: What about making the icons (and related actions) pluggable? Everyone would be able to define his own list of sharing actions.

Comment: @AndrewT. WhatsApp blocked, LINE blocked, Telegram blocked, Viber blocked. Reddit may not be blocked in China, but isn't quite the place in China where you're exchanging with most schoolmates, colleagues and friends.

Comment: @alexolut Not sure that "fair" applies here. SE sites are designed with English-language audience in mind, despite a few sites in other languages being added to the network. And the major social networks on the English-language internet are what they are.